# WCF Net.Tcp Binding and customUserNamePasswordValidatorType

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF service with Net.Tcp binding, my server configuration is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Service.PlainUserNameValidator, Service" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Service.TestService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Service.ITestService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/Service/TestService/" />
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8001/service/TestServiceMex/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In the configuration I turned on `customUserNamePasswordValidatorType`. The code to start the host is

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService)))
        {
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Metadata is at {0}?WSDL", host.Description.Endpoints[0].Address));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And my custom username validator class registered in config file is

```
namespace Service
{
    using System;
    using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;

    public class PlainUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Requesting username {0} and password {1}.", userName, password);
        }
    }
}
```

However the validator never seems to fire while the client is calling.

Any special trick I need to notice to enable `customUserNamePasswordValidatorType` for `Net.Tcp` binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points:

You havent included a certificate, you should do so to ensure the integrity of the client's credentials, set up a temporary one if you have to and add this to your service credentials.

```
<serviceCertificate 
          findValue="localhost" 
            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" 
            storeLocation="CurrentUser" 
            storeName="My" />
```

You also havent specified any security - for this to work, both client and service endpoints need to enable Username and Password authentication mode on their bindings

```
<netTcpBinding>
  <binding name="tcpWithMessageSecurity">
    <security mode="Message" >
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
    </security>
  </binding> 
</netTcpBinding>
```

then

```
<endpoint address="" binding="tcpWithMessageSecurity" contract="Service.ITestService">
```

Then, name your behavior and add it in the above line.